# Dealing with current short-term job

Tags: interviewing, resume

I'm working for an IT company since 2 months, i did it because I was desperate. i have been planning to change my career and move on to financial sector, did an internship previously in financial sector and have management degree. I just received an email notifying about interview in one of the reputed financial company.

How should I mention my 2 months of employment in resume or should I leave it off ? I'm currently employed by an IT company.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given that the current job is in a different field from your current qualifications and your internship, it should be okay to include and explain why you are leaving after such a short time.

Just respond with something like:

> At the time there were no roles in my chosen field available, so I needed to take on an interim role until something more appropriate came up.  This role came up sooner than I expected, but I would very much like to work in [my chosen field].

You should *definitely* include the experience on your CV.  Working history is very important to include if you do not have many jobs you have done.  Make sure you include very obviously your relevant qualifications and internships.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; here is brief of Working experience

- Working on online music related website I co-founded during college 
days, with roles like photography, content writing and general admin.
- Internship in Class in A financial sector
- Digital Marketing in IT company

Education - bachelor in management

Skill ;
basic knowledge of HTML, CSS, PHP, also in marketing, accounting, management etc.

Comment: @Nepallic Why are you saying all this? That sounds like a follow up question (without actually asking a question).

Answer (score 0):

You should definitely include the employment in your resume, as it does count under experience.

> How should I mention my 2 months of employment in resume?

You mention it in the same way as any other experience. [A similar answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55432/should-i-add-a-new-job-1-week-onto-my-resume/55529#55529) of mine shows you how you mention the experience on your resume(and/or) LinkedIn

Comment: Since I'm currently working on this company; it would look like Aug-Current.What if the recruiter ask why you want to switch so fast etc. and I don't want to make myself look like job hopper.

Comment: You can tell him that you went to the IT sector for gaining experience at software, but owing to your keen interest in finance(_mention your internship here_), you have made the switch quickly to pursue a professional career in finance.

Comment: Thanks for the advice; here is brief of Working experience - Working on online music related website I co-founded during college days, with roles like photography, content writing and general admin. - Internship in Class in A financial sector - Digital Marketing in IT company Education - bachelor in management Skill ; basic knowledge of HTML, CSS, PHP, also in marketing, accounting, management etc.

Comment: Please go ahead and add them in the resume.  (If you want help in how they are to be included, feel free to refer to: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/55432/should-i-add-a-new-job-1-week-onto-my-resume/55529#55529)